# setInterval doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I have a image and I'm trying to animate it through `setInterval()` . My aim is to move the image up by a certain pixel only when the user clicks on the `Canvas` else the image should be moving downwards.Everything goes well but the timer increases the speed for every `onclick()`

my canvas tag

```
 <canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="600" onclick=init()></canvas>
```

java script:

```
function init()
{

    function draw1()
    {
        context.clearRect(0,0,400,600);
        img_y = img_y - 40;
        context.drawImage(image1,img_x,img_y);

    }
    function move()
    {

        context.clearRect(0,0,400,600);
        img_y = img_y + 7;
        context.drawImage(image1,img_x,img_y);

    }
    draw1();
    setInterval(move,70);


}
```

My animation starts when the user clicks the `Canvas` of my game. When I click the `Canvas` for the second time or so,the animation speed increases. What is wrong with my logic?

Comment: You're starting a new interval timer on each click. The old ones keep running.

Comment: Yea I got that! So,how do I achieve what I'm trying?

Comment: Keep track of whether there's a timer running, and if there is, then don't start another one.

Comment: Do you want it to continually move up after the `click`? Or, will it move up only when you `click`?

Comment: When you draw on canvas, please use `window.requestAnimationFrame` (works the same as setTimeout, but it's optimized for rendering) and then only update the positions of your entities (in your case the image) every x milliseconds (rendering and position processing will be decorrelated)

Comment: can you give me a simple example of `window.requestAnimationFrame`? @topheman

Comment: there you are : http://codepen.io/topheman/pen/NPRRpg

Comment: That was a pretty useful one. Thanks:) @topheman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that each click ADDS an interval. So your code basically runs more times than you want (making your animation faster). Make sure to clear the interval before starting a new one. Try the following ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.clearInterval)):

```
window.myTimer = '';

function init()
{

    function draw1()
    {
        context.clearRect(0,0,400,600);
        img_y = img_y - 40;
        context.drawImage(image1,img_x,img_y);

    }
    function move()
    {

        context.clearRect(0,0,400,600);
        img_y = img_y + 7;
        context.drawImage(image1,img_x,img_y);

    }
    draw1();
    window.clearInterval(window.myTimer); // clear previous interval
    window.myTimer = setInterval(move,70); // set it again


}
```

Comment: That was a perfect answer! Thanks.

Comment: Hey! I have added another image in my canvas now,that image stays still. So when ever I start my game the other image gets cleared due to the `clearRect()` . I need only my previous draw image to get cleared not the new one too. Can you help? @Yotam Omer

Comment: @question Yes no problem. Instead of one clearRect you will have to do 4. Clear only the area around the new pic. Lets say your new image is in coordinates (100,100,300,300) you will have to do: clearRect(0,0,100,600), clearRect(300,0,400,600), clearRect(100,0,300,100), clearRect(100,300,300,600)

Comment: @question Another option is to clear the entire canvas like you did but each time add the image again.

Answer (score 0):

As @Pointy pointed out,, you are increasing the 'speed' every click, because you are creating a new interval which is calling that same function.

Consider either clearing the interval and making a new one each time : `window.clearInterval(intervalId);`
OR
implementing a bool within your function which will prevent its movement until click.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up the code that initiates movement with the code that moves the object up. They need to be separate functions.

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="600" onclick="moveUp"></canvas>
```

JS:

```
var movement = 7, timer;
function animate() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 600);
    img_y += 7;
    context.drawImage(image1, img_x, img_y);
}
function moveUp() { 
// no need to redraw the image here as it will be drawn at the next frame anyway
    img_y -= 40;
}
function init() {             // call this when you want the main animation to start
    if (timer) {              // if timer variable already exists
        clearInterval(timer); // clear the corresponding interval
        timer = null;         // and also clear the variable itself
    }
    timer = setInterval(animate, 70);
}
```

(This code clears the timer before setting it, in case, for some reason, `init` is called more than once.)

Comment: if(timer){ .. } I don't get this. Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

You could also work with the onmouseup, onmousedown events, letting it move as long mouse is pressed, and stop moving when mouse is no longer pressed. This way you can create and remove the interval on both events

```js
var interval;

function startInterval() {
  interval = setInterval(animation.move.bind(animation), 70);
}

function stopInterval() {
  clearInterval(interval);
}


var animation = {
  old: undefined,
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  context: undefined,
  move: function() {
    this.y += 10;
    animation.draw();
  },
  draw: function() {
    if (typeof animation.context === 'undefined') {
      var el = document.getElementById('ctx');
      animation.context = el.getContext('2d');
    }
    var context = animation.context;
    if (typeof animation.old !== 'undefined') {
      context.clearRect(animation.old.x, animation.old.y, 10, 10);
    }
    animation.old = {
      x: animation.x,
      y: animation.y
    };
    context.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    context.fillRect(animation.old.x, animation.old.y, 10, 10);
  }
};
```

```html
<canvas id="ctx" width="300" height="300" onmousedown="startInterval()" onmouseup="stopInterval()"></canvas>
```